# Facebook iOS SDK - Custom Delegate

Tags: ios, facebook, delegates

I am working on a new project with facebook integration. The app has to make different requests to facebook. The SDK provides one delegate that handles every request the same. Now i need to have a custom delegate to handle certain request different. Could somebody give me a hint on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Facebook class exposes numerous method which return FBRequest* objects, and each of those methods have an argument for a delegate, which can be any object you like, so long as it conforms to the FBRequestDelegate protocol.

Therefore either, just have a custom class which implements the protocol for each type of request. Or, have one class, which implements the protocol, and inside those methods, you'll need to inspect the FBRequest that you receive to determine what to do. So, for example, if you're calling:

```
Facebook *fb = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kYourFacebookAppId];
[params setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"PostComment"];
[fb requestWithParams:params andDelegate:delegate];
[fb release];
```

then in the delegate, you could do something like:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    // Make a decision based on the request
    if ([[request.params objectForKey:@"PostComment"] boolValue]) {
        // Here we should post a comment.

    }
}
```

However, I personally wouldn't do that, as it'll be much harder to maintain. Much better would be to write separate classes for each Facebook related task. These classes could inherit from a base FBDelegate class which does common things like error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try what you recommended. But just to be clear: it is not possible to call a certain method right from `[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/albums" andDelegate:self];`?

Sorry, but I'm new to Objective C and the Facebook SDK

Comment: Okay, so, this is asynchronous network programming, (which isn't easy to grok initially). So, what happens is, you call the requestWithGraphPath... and pass it your delegate. Once you call that, the program continues, and at some point the facebook object will get an answer, and your delegate method will be called with the result. Read up on http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18

Comment: Also, typically, you'll be calling this facebook request from within a view controller, so generally, you'd add the delegate methods to that view controller's implementation, and then add <FBRequestDelegate> as one of its protocols.

Comment: So the proper way would be to do it like he did? http://tylerwhitedesign.com/how-to-check-in-using-the-facebook-ios-sdk-and-graph-api

Comment: Yeah, that looks pretty thorough, maybe a bit verbose. My own uses of Facebook are just for authentication, and depending on what you need to do, you could probably bundle the delegate methods into your view controller. Still, nice find on that site.